# can i save an array of objects in a file in a human readable way?

Tags: java, arrays, file

I want to make an array of objects each object consists of some strings and I want to save this objects in a file in human readable way  ,, is there a method to  write and read the whole array at one time  or I have to save them element by element ??

Comment: You might look to [`XMLEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/beans/XMLEncoder.html) if you consider XML to be 'human readable'.

Comment: or the json format  http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Please post your code what you have so far...

Answer (score 0):

What exactly you mean by human readable way? Serialize the array and print it to a file if you feel the json data is good enough for you.

Ideally speaking it would be better to go element by element, as each object is independent individually as I don't see a way to apply a generic logic for all those objects.

Comment: I mean to have an array  of objects, the format of each object is something like " firstName,Lastname,..."  and  I want to save the whole array and call the whole array at a time,  also when I open the file I would like to see this format  " firstName,Lastname,..."   , so serlialization has nothing to do with this . I am sorry for interption

Comment: Serialisation has something to do with this bro. That can be used if you want to convert an object to a string and pass it across. Since your array contains user defined objects, its you who should say what exactly should be stored. So I see no other way apart from doing it element by element. Whats the problem with that by the way?

Comment: PhoneBook ob= new PhoneBook("mmmm","nnn","010");
  
         try{
         FileOutputStream file=new FileOutputStream("contacts.ser");
  
              ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
  
  out.writeObject(ob);
  out.close();
  file.close();
  }

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the main thing you are asking is 'can I write ... the whole array at one time'.

Sure:

```
String[] things = { "ABC", "XYZ" };
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(things));
```

I believe you are asking this question because when you try this:

```
System.out.println(things)
```

you get something like:

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@35a8767
```

What you see here is the array reference itself. What you wanted was a pretty print version like above. These pretty outputs come from custom implementations of the `toString` function, a function present on all objects in Java, coming from the `Object` object itself. As an array is a 'primitive', not an object, it does not have a `toString` function. Thus, the `Arrays` object provides a utility static `toString` function for just this purpose.

Another solution would be to use a `List` instead of an array. `List` is an object and has a pretty `toString` function.

```
List<String> thingList = Arrays.asList(things);
System.out.println(thingList);
```

Now, if you write this out to a file and want to read it back in (like you alluded to) you will be getting into the world of parsing. If you intend to write objects to a file and read them back in, you should definitely look into existing tools to serialize and deserialize your objects to XML or JSON (which are somewhat human readable serialization formats).